# JGoodies... FormLayout 

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jgoodies, form-layout

Ok so i am trying to get a 3 JPanel JFrame where right and left panel have a fixed width but are vertically re-sizable and a center panel that can be re-sized both horizontally and vertically.

Since standard LayoutManagers are terrible and simply annoying i have been told that the industry standard and easiest to work whit and handle is JGoodies. However seems that a lot of link on JGoodies website are dead regarding their examples / tutorials there is a 400 page PDF i dont want to read.

Anyhow i have started implementing FormLayout to my first UI_View and i ran in to a problem

```
package ppe.view;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.*;

public class UI_View extends JFrame
{
    private JScrollPane right   = new JScrollPane();
    private JList       browse  = new JList();

    public UI_View()
    {
        this.setTitle("Prototype MVC Arhitecture");
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        FormLayout layout = new FormLayout("right:pref, 7dlu","p, 1dlu");
        layout.setColumnGroups(new int [][]{{1}});
        JPanel content = new JPanel(layout);

        CellConstraints c = new CellConstraints();
        right.add(browse);
        content.add(right, c.xy(1, 1));
        this.add(content);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new UI_View().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is another PDF which is more then sufficient to get you started with the `FormLayout` and does not require a 400page read: [tutorial](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=formlayout%20jgoodies&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jgoodies.com%2Farticles%2Fforms.pdf&ei=76D7TpWuIYTrOZz_5KIC&usg=AFQjCNH6uYWbCRAyrzOkgAs5Blj8ToMv9Q&cad=rja)

Comment: -1 for "Since standard LayoutManagers are terrible and simply annoying" and for being arrogant without knowledge. Different layout managers have their place depending on your application. By the way, `FormLayout` is NOT the industry standard layout manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You a missing a Jar file. JGoodies has several Jar files, make sure you have the ones you need.

Comment: Thanks for the tip seems i was missing JGoodies Commons. Any chance you can tell me why the JScrollPanel that contains JList is not appearing on the JFrame. The JFrame is shown but no JList.

Comment: Sorry, I have been away from Swing too long. From a short inspection it looks like things are hosed up right. Maybe you need to do a refresh or layout on your frame?

Comment: You should call `right.setViewportView(browse)`, not `right.add(...)`

Answer (score 0):

[MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is the best layout manager I've used, but I like JGoodies for its Binding and Validation libraries. You can find tutorial code samples in the older versions in the [download archive](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/archive/).

What also might make your life easier is to use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the [WindowBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) plugin. It's a layout tool that [supports FormLayout](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/layoutmanagers/swing/).